# What does it take to get a War from Play 2.1.1 for deployment into Glassfish Server

Tags: playframework-2.0, maven-3, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I have been trying to deploy a Play 2.1.1 application that has been running in Netty as a stand alone web application. For IS/Infrastructure purposes we are obliged to host the application in Glassfish. We have been building the War with the 
`<id>play2-war-support</id>
 <url>http://repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>` maven plugin.

I have noticed that this builds a war file which we have to manually remove dependencies from it as there are namespace clashes with libraries already contained within Glassfish.

We are using Websockets, I have also read that Websockets are only supported in Servlet 3.1+

I tried deploying the War to a Glassfish both 3 and 4 server and it failed with the message when attempting to access any of the routes defined in the Play application.

**HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0**

Are there any other modifications required to the War file, such as *.xml files that point Glassfish to the routes in play for instance.

Are there any good sources of information on this topic Play itself seems quite light on information.